# How do I use gawk to convert csv to xml?

Tags: mysql, xml, csv, awk, gawk

I want to create an executable file using awk (gawk) on Ubuntu 16.04 to convert a csv file to an xml file.  From what I gathered, the format needed is below.

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
NR==1 {
for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    tags[i] = $i
}
next
}
{
print "<whatever>"
for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    printf "    <%s>%s</%s>\n", tags[i], $i, tags[i]
}
print "</whatever>"
}
```

How do I tell awk to insert each field and repeat until the end of the file?

input

```
$ cat file.csv
id,color,status
7,black,open
52,white,closed
```

output

```
awk -f tst.awk file.csv
<whatever>
    <id>7</id>
    <color>black</color>
    <status>open</status>
</whatever>
<whatever>
    <id>52</id>
    <color>white</color>
    <status>closed</status>
</whatever>
```

This prints to the screen but I need it in an output file.  I also need to put true if certain field is 1 and false if certain field is 0.

needed output example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Batch>
  <ASWFileVersion>
  <BatchHeader>
    <BatchId>965</BatchId>
    <UserBatchId>965</UserBatchId>
  </BatchHeader>
  <BatchCustomer>
     <EmployeeNumber>123456</EmployeeNumber>
     <FirstName>fname</FirstName>
     <LastName>lname</LastName>
     <Employee>true </Employee>
  </BatchCustomer>
  <BatchCustomer>
     <EmployeeNumber>654321</EmployeeNumber>
     <FirstName>first</FirstName>
     <LastName>lastn</LastName>
     <Employee>false</Employee>
  </BatchCustomer>
</Batch>
```

There is no header to the file and fields are not in order they must appear in xml.  There is a boolean 1 or 0 value that must be translated to true or false.

Comment: What is `30.3930000` in the time? Is the fractional part supposed to be seven digits (hundreds of nanoseconds/tenths of microseconds)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too much text in your question to wade through, but here's in general how to convert CSV to XML with awk since that seems to be the root of your question:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        tags[i] = $i
    }
    next
}
{
    print "<whatever>"
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf "    <%s>%s</%s>\n", tags[i], $i, tags[i]
    }
    print "</whatever>"
}

$ cat file.csv
id,color,status
7,black,open
52,white,closed

$ awk -f tst.awk file.csv
<whatever>
    <id>7</id>
    <color>black</color>
    <status>open</status>
</whatever>
<whatever>
    <id>52</id>
    <color>white</color>
    <status>closed</status>
</whatever>
```

Hope that helps. If not then edit your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: Can you explain the elements of your script?  This is my first foray into awk, so I don't know any syntax.  I am editing my question (but leaving the detailed portion in place because it is necessary to understand the format I must reproduce)

Comment: I made as concise as possible.  I don't understand much of what Ed Morton posted above since I dont have experience with awk before now.  Can I get explanations of the steps so I understand what I need to change?

Comment: OK I figured out why I was getting confused by the sample you posted I didn't realize that it was code, input, output.  I thought it was all code, it has been a late night.  I had input and output in original post but I eliminated it when you said it was too much code.  Adding it back now.

Comment: I created your input file file.csv, and created the tst.awk file then ran awk -f tst.awk file.csv but the curser just blinks and after 15 minutes it never completes running or produces an output file of any kind.  I had to ctrl+c to get back to the prompt.  This is with only the two lines from your file.csv test file just to test output.  I made no edits yet.  Fully updated Ubuntu Server 16.04.  Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: I edited question to reflect progress, gawk causes it to hang up but awk it runs ok.  I can fiddle with it to produce nearly all of what I need, I just need to know how to a) export true for 1 and false for 0 only for one column, and b) insert some fields that are static between the fields that are produced from columns.  I am beginning to understand how this works, not sure how to accomplish those two tasks still.

Comment: It is possible there was a typo, but that was what I experienced.  I assumed some syntax changed with the variant.  It is working, with both gawk and awk.  I experimented with another method in between trying gawk and awk so it is likely I had a typo and made an assumption.  How do I get it to output to a file?  If I append > output.xml it only will run as root, sudo doesn't allow it.

Comment: I have only been using linux for a few months and am still learning much of the capabilities.  I don't mind at all the clues that force me to find what I need myself so thank you.  
I was expecting that I would do a single output at the command line but now I see that the output has to be done for every print command.  
Any ideas on how to have output skip a static entry?  Example:
awk print field1 from file,
awk print field2 from file,
awk print static line with no variables,
awk print field3 from variable

Comment: I meant that I need to figure out how to interrupt the loop, print a static line of text (like you said I know how to print the static line of text) and then pick up the loop where it left off, completing the loop through the rest of the columns.  Example:  <tag>field 1</tag> <tag>field 2</tag> <tag>static text</tag> <tag>field 3</tag>

Comment: Thank you, I will play around with that. .